# How can I iterate image processing through a directory of image files in a sub folder within Python?

Tags: python, list, iterator, directory

Needing help specifically with how to connect an iterated list (declared as fileListL) which is dynamically built from a sequence of image files within a sub directory (left) and loops through until it reaches the end of the frame range. All of the script works as intended on a single frame but I am not able to get this to loop through multiple frames. Ideas, thoughts?

```
# this module runs within a root directory that contains one sub folder named 'left' and 15 sub folders expressed in the dirL as ('left/01','left/02, . . . .)
# each folder can have any number of sequential .jpg images in the format 'name.0000.jpg'

import os
import sys
import glob
import Image
from itertools import izip, count

# create Master List of files in Left Directories along with a count of files

global fileListL
fileListL = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'left/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.jpg'):
                fileListL.append('left/'+file)
print fileListL

# Iterator
global inFrame
global outFrame
inFrame = 'left/test.0000.jpg' # testing temp needs dynamic variable, trying to use fileList L list to dynamically increment thru frames
outFrame = inFrame[5:-5]
crops = ((0, 0, 1920, 1080),(1920, 0, 3840, 1080), (3840, 0, 5760, 1080), (5760, 0, 7680, 1080), (7680, 0, 9600, 1080), (9600, 0, 11520, 1080), (11520, 0, 13440, 1080), (13440, 0, 15360, 1080), (15360, 0, 17280, 1080), (17280, 0, 19200, 1080), (19200, 0, 21120, 1080), (21120, 0, 23040, 1080), (23040, 0, 24960, 1080), (24960, 0, 26880, 1080), (26880, 0, 28800, 1080))
quads = ('01_', '02_', '03_', '04_', '05_', '06_', '07_', '08_', '09_', '10_', '11_', '12_', '13_', '14_', '15_')
dirL= ('left/01/', 'left/02/', 'left/03/', 'left/04/', 'left/05/', 'left/06/', 'left/07/', 'left/08/', 'left/09/', 'left/10/', 'left/11/', 'left/12/', 'left/13/', 'left/14/', 'left/15/')

for i in fileListL:
    for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(inFrame) ):
        print "current file is: " + infile
        oL = Image.open(inFrame) # needs dynamic variable for frames
        for i, each_quad, each_frame, each_dirL in izip(count(), crops, quads, dirL):
            print i, each_quad, each_frame, each_dirL
            frame = oL.crop(((each_quad)))
            frame.save((each_dirL)+(each_frame)+(outFrame)+'.png')
```

Comment: Do you get any error? Messages are printing ok?

Comment: No error when running the module on a single frame assigned to 'inFrame". Whenever I have more than one image in the root left directory it just writes over the same split images in all of the sub directories. so no error per se, just needing to get a loop that cycle s thru fileListL properly.

Comment: at `Image.open(inFrame)` do you always intend to open the same image?

Comment: No (inFrame) is currently set as a static value to make explaining the problem a bit easier. Ideally fileListL needs to iteratively feed into this value. Wondering if maybe I need to restructure everything a bit to slide the frame sequencing in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many "copy&paste" mistakes in your code that is hard to grasp it's purpose.

- nested `for` loops using the same name for loop variable (`i`).
- `os.path.join(inFrame)` expects a list containing path components, `inFrame` seems to be a string
- what is the purpose of the first for loop (`for i in fileListL`), seems like you are discarding `i`.
- and so on...

Please update the question with your file tree layout and the steps that work for a single file and perhaps we may help you.

[update]

Seems like your code could be simplified to something like:

```
for i, file_name in enumerate(glob.glob('left/*.jpg')):
    out_frame = 'left/%02d/%s.png' % (i+1, file_name[5:-5])
    print "current input file is: '%s', output file is: %s" % (file_name, out_frame)
    img = Image.open(file_name)
    for i, crop in enumerate(crops):
        frame = img.crop(crop)
        frame.save(out_frame)
```

It's untested code just to point you the right direction.

Comment: this runs within a root directory that contains one sub folder named 'left'- each folder can have any number of sequential .jpg images in the format 'name.0000.jpg', it splits a single image into 15 cropped and, re-named sub images and distributes them in to the 15 multiple sub folders. Hope that helps . . .

Comment: Hmmmm . . getting the error:    
out_frame = 'left/%02d/%s.png' % (i+1, filename[5:-5])
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Tried adding str(filename) and calling in a separate variable, but get the same error

Comment: @ROcketsLAsersandRObots: sorry, the code was lacking an "enumerate" to fill the loop variable `i`

Comment: Still no go. This is the new error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: @ROcketsLAsersandRObots: unfortunately you don't have enough reputation to move this conversation to SO chat. I just spoted an error at `Image.open` (should be file_name instead of inFrame).

Comment: Tweaked the frame.save on the last line and it's working like it's meant to by saving all of the individual cropped images into their declared sub directories. One problem left is that the iterator on the file save needs to save as a four digit integer tied directly to the original file_name open. I think I can get that part solved.

Comment: frame.save((each_dirL)+(each_frame)+(out_frame))